# How to dynamically query different DbSet types based on enum selection in ASP.NET application using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have 11 tables that share the same model (classes derived from a `BaseModel`) and I want to use the same frontend code to display / query / edit all of them. This seems to be not so easy with EF Core 7.

My model classes look like this:

```
public interface IPart
{
    [Key]
    int PartId { get; set; }
    string PartValue { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    string Symbol { get; set; }
    string Footprint { get; set; }
    string Price { get; set; }
    // Rest of the properties ...
}

public abstract class BasePart : IPart
{
    [Key]
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public string PartValue { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Symbol { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Footprint { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Price { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    // Rest of the properties ...
}

public class Resistor : BasePart
{
}

public class Capacitor : BasePart
{
}

public class Inductor : BasePart
{
}

// Rest of the derived models

public enum PartType
{
    Capacitor,
    Connector,
    Diode,
    Fuse,
    Inductor,
    IntegratedCircuit,
    Mechanical,
    Oscillator,
    Other,
    Resistor,
    Switch
}
```

What I wish to do is being able to select the `PartType` from a dropdown and then load the corresponding data from the matching dataset (e.g `DbSet<Capacitor>`) to an `IPart` list to display them in a data grid.

To not rewrite the same code 11 times this should be generic for all of these models, so that I can use the same datagrid and the same loading / editing / saving code.

But it seems that `DbSet` *REALLY* doesn't want to operate that way because of type safety reasons.

My ideal solution would have looked something like this:

```
void OnValueChanged(PartType? value)
{
    selectedDatabase = value;

    if (selectedDatabase.HasValue)
    {
        var partList = dbContext.Set(MapEnumToType(selectedDatabase.value)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this properly, or do I have to implement a repository and write all the code to handle all of this for each of the 11 models out by hand?

Comment: _"or do i have to implement a Repository "_ - EF **is** your repository - so don't worry, you won't.

Comment: @Dai There are many reasons still to implement a repository pattern on top of EF, Microsoft even has documentation on the best practice of how to do it.

I'm well aware that EF is a repository, and I would like to try to use it as one, but in this specific use case, it doesn't seem to work. I found many posts with a similar problem and no good solution.

Comment: If you're referrring to the same article I'm thinking of, that article doesn't cover wrapping-EF specifically...

Comment: From the ADD/EDIT cshtml screens, make sure to use only the BaseModel. - During the INSERT or UPDATE operation in the database, CAST from the BaseModel to the EF TABLE model and then do the INSERT or UPDATE operations. For casting from one class to another class you can use C# Casting or JSON Serialization and Deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got `interface IPart` which I assume you can use as a *generic constraint* in your `DbContext` to implement a safer guard over `DbContext.Set()`

Something like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TPart> GetDbSetForPart<TPart>()
        where TPart: class, IPart
    {
        return base.Set<TPart>();
    }
}
```

As you might have noticed, `DbSet<T>` is a `class`, which means it cannot support type-variance over `T` whereas `interface` types like `IQueryable<out T>` do - and fortunately `DbSet<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>`, so we *should* be able to do something like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public IQueryable<IPart> GetDbSetQuery( PartType partType )
    {
        switch( partType )
        {
        case PartType.Capacitor: return this.GetDbSetForPart<Capacitor>();
        case PartType.Connector: return this.GetDbSetForPart<Connector>();
        case PartType.Diode    : return this.GetDbSetForPart<Diode>();
        case PartType.Fuse     : return this.GetDbSetForPart<Fuse>();
        // etc
        // TIP: Use `ExhaustiveMatching` to get compile-time errors for non-exhaustive enum `switch` blocks: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExhaustiveMatching.Analyzer
        }
    }

    public DbSet<TPart> GetDbSetForPart<TPart>()
        where TPart: class, IPart
    {
        return base.Set<TPart>();
    }

//

    public IQueryable<IPart> AddNewPart<TPart>( TPart newPart )
        where TPart: class, IPart
    {
        DbSet<TPart> dbSet = this.GetDbSetForPart<TPart>();
        dbSet.Add( newPart );
    }
}
```

So you *should* be able to do this:

```
using( MyDbContext db = CreateDbContext() )
{
    List<IPart> loadedParts = await this.dbContext.GetDbSetQuery( PartType.Capacitor ).ToListAsync();


    TurboencabulatorPart newPart = new TurboencabulatorPart()
    {
        PartId      = ?,
        BasePlate   = "pre-famulated amulite surmounted by a malleable logarithmic casing",
        MainWinding = "lotus-o-delta type"
    };

    db.AddNewPart( newPart );

.   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Note that you won't be able to build complex queries when you're using `IPart`  - some `Expression<Func<>>` operations *might* work, and you could always implement them as extension-methods or a custom `IQueryable<T>` implementation (that wraps a `DbSet<T>` more closely).

---

Disclaimer: I have only done this with (the *classic*) EF 6, and not EF Core - YMMV. If it doesn't work in EF Core let me know in a comment-reply and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: This is indeed a really nice approach for Querying the data. But as far as I see it, an IQueryable can't be used to add or update the database, only read from it.

Is there an easy way to do all CRUD operations in a similar way?

Comment: @PatrickWalther Good catch - fortunately it's only a few more lines to support `DbSet<T>.Add` - I've updated my answer just now.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried it but the Problem is that on the other side the data grid calls the update function with an IPart and the code can't resolve that to one of the actual types. I don't really see why but it just wouldn't work. 

What worked now is that i added a "public void UpdatePart(IPart newPart)" function that gets the type from IPart and calls the correct Implementation to Update the Part. 

I'm sure there's a shorter way than my switch case solution but I couldn't get "public IQueryable<IPart> AddNewPart<TPart>( TPart newPart )" to run when passing an IPart.