# Limit type of generic injected into class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics

I'm wondering if something like this is possible in .NET6.

Given an application with 3 more databases, each using its own DbContext, create a generic DbContext over an entity like so:

```
public class DbRepository<TRepository, TEntity> : IDbRepository<TRepository, TEntity> where TRepository : IContext

services.AddScoped(typeof(IDbRepository<,>), typeof(DbRepository<,>));
```

With implementations:

```
public class FirstDbContext : IFirstDbContext
public class SecondDbContext : ISecondDbContext
```

Now a BaseService that is also of the same TRepository:

```
public class BaseService<TRepository> where TRepository : IContext
```

Can I limit what is passed into a Service based on the TRepository in BaseService?

So That:

```
public class UserService : BaseService<IFirstDbContext>
{
    public UserService(
        IDbRepository<IFirstDbContext, User>  userDbRepository, /* allowed */
        IDbRepository<ISecondDbContext, Invoice> invoiceDbRepository, /* not allowed */
    ) { }
}
```

If UserService is defined with `BaseService<IFirstDbContext>` then only allow injection of types `IDbRepository<IFirstDbContext, TEntity>`.

Comment: May I ask why you're using the generic-repository anti-pattern?

Comment: A lot of people will argue that you don't need Repository and UnitOfWork with EF: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/.

Comment: Not actually in use. This came out of a discussion with a coworker and I didn't know if the ability to limit like this existed.

Comment: @PalleDue I would agree actually. This question is really about generics and limiting types. I'll remove the EF tag.

Comment: You'll have to remove the types entirely because the DAO/CRUD classes shown have known conflicts with EF Core. Instead of demonstrating a problem this is showing bugs over bugs due *other* problems

Comment: BTW your own question is *caused* by the bad design. You want *specific* domain repositories but you can't get them because you wrapped them with low-level CRUD wrappers. Since EF already abstracts data access *and* querying *and* mapping almost to the domain level, the abstractions you need are almost at the domain level too, multi-entity as well, containing the specific queries or modifications needed for specific scenarios/bounded context/use cases/processes/pick a name. The interfaces themselves should have no reference to the ORM

Comment: To solve this at the type level, pass an `IProcurementRepository` or `IFulfillmentRepository` with members that are *not* involved with actually working with CRUD operations. You no longer have to restrict anything. Dealing with objects is the *implementation's* job. ORMs try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not tables, which is why they don't realy need CRUD methods. They detect changes to the objects they track and persist all of them at once. The NHibernate Session or EF DbContext are the UoW that tracks the changes, not the database connection

Comment: If you have `public class Service { public Service(int i, string s) { } }` can you limit type injected into class to be `int`. Well, yes, don't add it a `string` parameter. Your example injects concrete types (i.e., closed generic types), so what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I limit what is passed into a Service based on the `TRepository` in BaseService?

Yes - ish.

---

A common technique (well, at least for me) is to add a marker interface to all of my EF entity `class` types so that I can add it as a generic-type-parameter-constraint as a *sanity-check* in generic methods that I write over, say, `DbSet<T>`, to ensure `T` is an actual EF entity class type rather than any-ol'-.NET-type (after-all, using `DbSet<String>` will compile, even though that's just silly) - usually this just looks like `interface IEntity {}`.

(For a somewhat relevant example, see how I use `interface IPart` [in my answer to this other QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76597144/159145))

I'd like to stress that this `IEntity` type **is not foolproof**: it's entirely possible for downstream consumers to implement `IEntity` themselves and pass their types into the constrained generic methods and break things - but that's not something we're worried about at this point.

Moving on, first, let's ditch the `interface` types for each `DbContext` (i.e. `IFirstDbContext` and `ISecondDbContext`): that's just unnecessary: instead of specifying `IFirstDbContext` just specify `FirstDbContext` directly (though if you *really* want to keep those interfaces and use them, you can - but you're just creating extra legwork for yourself; you're never going to need to mock a `DbContext` so I just don't see the point in having an `interface` for a `DbContext` type (*excepting* some kind of `IReadOnlyDbContext`, but that's another topic).

---

Considering the `interface IEntity`  So let's generalize that out to a single generic interface:

```
interface IEntity<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
{
}
```

...then add that interface to your entity types: `User`, `Invoice`, and `Some2ndDbContextEntity`:

```
partial class User : IEntity<FirstDbContext>
{
}

partial class Invoice : IEntity<FirstDbContext>
{
}

partial class Some2ndDbContextEntity: IEntity<SecondDbContext>
{
}
```

<sub>I'm very opposed to the concept of generic-repositories, so I'm only re-using the OP's `IDbRepository<TContext,TEntity>` interface here to illustrate the point I'm making - and *not* as an example of how C# programs should be written.</sub>

So let's modify your `IDbRepository` to add some constraints:

```
interface IDbRepository<TContext,TEntity>
    where TContext : DbContext 
    where TEntity  : class, IEntity<TContext>
{
}
```

So then inside `UsersService` we can now use `IDbRepository<,>`:

```
class GoodUserService
{
    public GoodUserService(
        IDbRepository<FirstDbContext,User>    usersRepository,
        IDbRepository<FirstDbContext,Invoice> invoicesRepository
    )
    {
    }
}
```

...but if we try to use `IDbRepository` for `Invoice` with `SecondDbContext` - or for `Some2ndDbContextEntity` with `FirstDbContext` then the generic constraints will be violated:

```
class BadUserService
{
    public BadUserService(
        IDbRepository<FirstDbContext,User                  > usersRepository,
        IDbRepository<FirstDbContext,Some2ndDbContextEntity> badRepository
    )
    {
    }
}
```

Indeed, we see a compile-time error if we do that:

[image]

Comment: This is helpful. I regret using a dbRepository as my example though. Kind of distracts from the generics question.

Comment: @AndrewGrothe note that this limits the generics passed to the `IDbRepository` (does not matter what it is called), not the parameters you can pass to the `UserService`, i.e. you can still do `UserService : BaseService<IFirstDbContext>` And ctor `UserService (IDbRepository<ISecondDbContext, EntityFromSecondDbContext> invoiceDbRepository)`

Answer (score 2):

No, at least using language type system. The only thing you can do - write [custom Roslyn analyzer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/) which will process your files and emit corresponding warnings/errors.

Comment: The problem here is the bad design. Instead of high level interfaces, low-level CRUDs *bound* to a specific implementation are used. Instead of an `IProcurementRepository` this shows a bunch of `IRepo<IProcurementContext,User>>`, ``IRepo<IProcurementContext,Invoice>>`

Comment: Thanks, in hindsight, I should have used a better example, this was the first thing I thought of to illustrate the point but ended up on a rabbit trail.